# Call Stored Procedure from Entity Framework that returns compound object

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a database first setup in .net6
I need to call a stored proc (Lets say it is called GetMyData)

The stored proc is going to return 5 columns from various tables and so does not map to a current entity model.

The only things I can find is to use the context model to return a stored proc result but that will not work as the result set does not map to an existing model. Or a convoluted ADO.Net style call that looks horrific and needs lots of code.

Is there a simple way to call a stored proc that returns various columns from many tables?

Comment: Use `Dapper` or register result entity in Model. `modelBuilder.Entity<SPResult>().HasNokey()`, should be enough.

Comment: EF Core Power Tools can map the parameters and creates the result class for you

Comment: If I create the model will it get wiped the next time the context is generated?